# How change the password of default email wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, email, passwords, smtp

I have a big problem with my site Wordpress, i have changed the password of the default mail wordpress ( the mail used in the first installation wordpress ).
Now is impossible send mail to new users than sign in on my site.

How can I change the password in wordpress, for the default mail ?
Where is the configuration file for send email ( SMTP user and password ) ?

Greetings.

Comment: smtp details are not used in default wp

Comment: Can i resolve this problem ? @David

Comment: i dont really know what the details are, is it your own smtp server or a external service? Or are you using php mail? Or is it just you have lost the password for the admin account in wordpress and this has nothing to do with the php process of sending emails?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution

Here is a code snippet example with comments for each setting to configure WordPress to sent SMTP email:

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email' );
function send_smtp_email( $phpmailer ) {

// Define that we are sending with SMTP
$phpmailer->isSMTP();

// The hostname of the mail server
$phpmailer->Host = "smtp.example.com";

// Use SMTP authentication (true|false)
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;

// SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$phpmailer->Port = "587";

// Username to use for SMTP authentication
$phpmailer->Username = "yourusername";

// Password to use for SMTP authentication
$phpmailer->Password = "yourpassword";

// Encryption system to use - ssl or tls
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";

$phpmailer->From = "you@yourdomail.com";
$phpmailer->FromName = "Your Name";
}
```

To use this snippet, you will need to adjust the settings according to your email service requirements. Check with your host.
The snippet, once configured, can be added to your theme’s functions.php file.